# any workaround for CFileHelper::createDirectory undefiend in yii 1.1.14?

Tags: yii

I'm having problem with the mkdir permission denied error in the server.
so instead of using mkdir, I altered my code and used CFileHelper::createDirectory instead.

```
CFileHelper::createDirectory('pathOfDirectory'.'/'.777,true)
```

it did worked in my local using 1.1.16 ..but then when I pushed it to server. function is undefined. I don't know if this function really doesn't exist in Yii 1.1.14. as our live server uses this version. any solution for this? given the situation I am not allowed to chmod or create a directory in server and only let the application create directory by itself programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I did, I created a PHP class, placed it inside the components directory and extends the CFileHelper.php ...then from there, I added the createDirectory() function that doesn't exist in Yii 1.1.14.. solved the problem :D

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem that you have a typing error. Try following:

```
CFileHelper::createDirectory('pathOfDirectory'.'/', 777, true);
```

Anyway, if you look at the implementation of the `createDirectory()` function, you will see, that this is nothing else than `mkdir` and `chmod`:

```
public static function createDirectory($dst,$mode=null,$recursive=false)
{
    if($mode===null)
        $mode=0777;
    $prevDir=dirname($dst);
    if($recursive && !is_dir($dst) && !is_dir($prevDir))
        self::createDirectory(dirname($dst),$mode,true);
    $res=mkdir($dst, $mode);
    @chmod($dst,$mode);
    return $res;
}
```

So there is actually no difference besides that your web-user and your ssh-user could be different.

Comment: I downloaded the 1.1.14. it's confirmed, only that function doesn't exist in that class. why am I so unlucky....and yes , I know it's only a recursive version of mkdir and chmod..but if that function is part of the core yii in my server, the function works..but if I use plain mkdir, it won't work..unless I will make directory manually and chmod it in server

Comment: There is no problem to add the function yourself.

Comment: unfortunately, I am not allowed to modify the core framework copy in the server. adding the function to my ordinary helper files nor some ordinary php files won't work at all...but when I created a helper file that "extends" the CFileHelper, it actually worked